# Android Splash Screen Timer Does not Work Properly

Tags: android, android-layout, timer, splash-screen

In my app i set the splash screen timer to 5 sec and later on think that 5 sec is too long so i change it back to 1 sec and my splash screen doesn't seen on the screen and keep me waiting for more than 5 sec i couldn't find what is wrong so here is my Splashscreen code

```
    public class Splash extends Activity
{
    private Timer_Countdown timer_Countdown = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen);
        timer_Countdown = new Timer_Countdown(5000, 1000);
        timer_Countdown.start();
    }

    class Timer_Countdown extends CountDownTimer
    {
        public Timer_Countdown(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
            super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            timer_Countdown.cancel();
            Intent startIntent;
            startIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAINMENU");
            startActivity(startIntent);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        finish();
    }
    }
```

And one last thing if I change it back to 5 sec it shows up on the screen again.

Comment: It's God's way of telling you that splash screens are evil.  Please reconsider. http://cyrilmottier.com/2012/05/03/splash-screens-are-evil-dont-use-them/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why you are using this much of code just to use splash screen. Make it simple, you can use below code.

```
public class Splash extends Activity {

    Timer timer = new Timer();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
               public void run() {
                   Intent intent = new Intent(Splash.this, NewActivity.class);
                   startActivity(intent);
                               finish();
               }
            }, 2000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Change timer `5000` with any seconds you want if you want for 1 seconds then make it like this `1000`

Comment: Same problem if i set the number less than 5 it doesn't show up on the screen

Comment: Just copy above full code and replace with your code. It will hold your screen for 2 seconds and then automatically moves to next screen.

Comment: I think i fix it.Thanks a lot for your quick asnwer.

Comment: And one last thing if I add onPasuse method it gives me trouble.

Comment: What you are passing in onPause method and where you are placing it.

Comment: I'm not passing anything and I'm placing it under your code to call finish() method

Comment: Then directly finish method after startActivity, no need to pass onpause method. See for my updated answer pass finish over there.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Handler also

```
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this, YourNewActivity.class));
            finish();

        }
    }, 3000);
```

or Using Timer with Timer Schedule

```
public class Splash extends Activity {

 Timer t= new Timer();

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);
    t.schedule(new TimerTask() {
           public void run() {
               Intent n= new Intent(Splash.this, YourNewActivity.class);
               startActivity(n);
           }
        }, 3000);
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead of Timer

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                //code for starting new activity

            }
        }, 5000);
```